# Getting position (xy coordinates) of string in pdf file using iText

Tags: java, itext

Given a PDF template with notations of where to insert different info, 
my mission is to detect those notations and to replace them with dynamic data 
received from an html form. for instance, the template can look like this:

```
|FNAME||SNAME|

|TELCAP||PHONE1|
|CELLCAP||MOBILE|
|EMAIL|
|WEB|
```

and I have to replace `|FNEME|` with a name I receive via a form.

1. Is there a way of getting the position of, for instance |FNAME|,
   with `iText` **functions** so I know where to insert the first name?
2. Also, after getting the position, is there a way of deleting
   `|FNAME|` and replacing it with the name received dynamically from
   my html form?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about getting the position of a "string" in a PDF with iText, but I know about getting the position of a form field in a PDF with iText.  A form, in case you don't know the term, is a PDF document with fields that are named and might be fillable by an end-user if the form is presented in an environment where that's possible.

You create a PdfWriter and PdfReader, get the form template, and then a collection of what iText calls "AcroFields":

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 18, 18, 18, 18);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new  FileOutputStream(<<fileoutputpath>>);
DirectContent content = write.getDirectContent();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("<pdf form file specification>");
PdfImportedPage template = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1); // gets first page
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
```

the creator of the form will give a field name to each of the fillable fields; you can get
the position and size of the rectangle covered by that field with that name:

```
float[] positions = acroFields.getFieldPositions("<fieldName>");
```

and then write your value to that position in place of the field name:

```
ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(contentByte);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(new Phrase(value, fontToUse), pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, false);
columnText.go(false);
```

I know this is pretty complicated, and unfortunately still incomplete, but I was reluctant to explain it fully before I/we even know that using a form is an option for you.  The iText library will do this, but there's no *simple* way to do it that I know of.

Comment: thaks alot for your detailed answer

Comment: Just wanted to ask if writing to the same position of the field will override the field? (I don't want fields to appear in the final PDF file).

Comment: Removing the fields is an operation the iText people call "flattening"; I forget how to set the output PDF to be flattened, I'll have to look that up tomorrow.  Flattening removes the field information from the form, so fields will not appear in the result.  You might find examples of flattening on the web - that's where I found them - but a lot of the ones I find with a quick search have to do with XFA and with the use of PdfStamper, neither of which apply here.  I tried using the PdfStamper method but found it to be 2 or 3 orders of magnitude slower than this one, for what I was doing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand how the code I wrote does what it does.  I found the entire iText process to be driven by example-hunting and trial-and-error, which I find frustrating, but I found no other choice.  I bought the first edition of the book; it gives examples, but doesn't explain things.  As near as I can tell, there is a "direct content" and an "under content" to add to the resulting form, and the under content must not include the fields; what is added is obtained with "getTemplate()".  If you want to send me an email via private message, we can discuss in more depth.

Comment: iv'e got the book iText in action. i'll read the chapter about creating and processing form fields so i can use your advice.